# UIView animations intermittently fail, app-wide

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, animatewithduration

Occasionally, my app will simply not render any frame-relayed animations triggered by [`+[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:) and friends.

The `completion` block, when provided, still gets called as I'd expect, but the views simply "snap" into the destination frame, as if I'd simply called `-setFrame:`.

It is across the whole app, and is completely independent of which view controller is displaying, and whether or not the VC is modally presented. Restarting the app solves the problem temporarily.

*Note: This is obviously not enough information to solve the problem, but I'm not even sure where to begin. Comments on where to start debugging are **greatly** appreciated.*

**Update:** It seems to be reproducible by running a series of animations in succession. If I trigger several animations to run overtop of each other, it would seem animations just turn off, app-wide.

Comment: Is this in iOS 7 or iOS 8? It makes a huge difference, because the behavior of view animations has totally changed.

Comment: You can't show _any_ example code?

Comment: @matt Happens on both iOS 7 and 8. Would love to show example code, but I'm not sure where to start. There are dozens of `animateWithDuration` calls to set frames throughout the codebase and, when this happens, all of them fail.

Comment: Conflicting animations on the same property usually _do_ cancel the animation; indeed, that's the standard _way_ of canceling an animation (as I explain here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#SECblockbasedviewanimation).

Comment: Well, you ask "where to begin" and "where to start". Start with a new clean project with just _two_ animations and try to reproduce the problem. When you can, you have a reproducible test case. Until then, you can't debug and no one can help.

Comment: @matt But would that cause _all_ animations to cancel? Or just that conflicting one?

Comment: Great question but without a specific example it's hard to answer. I've never seen that, but it may be that you've tied some knot that I am failing to envision.

Comment: Just to give a wild hypothetical example, suppose you call `animateWithDuration` nested inside an existing animation block. This might cause all sorts of weird effects, especially since a lot of the features of the surrounding animation are _inherited_ by the nested animation by default.

Comment: Here's another wild hypothetical example: how to I know that somewhere down the chain you are not calling `setDisableActions:`? That would kill all subsequent animations - that's its job.

Comment: So unless you can reproduce the problem and show some code, we're all just whistling in the dark.

Comment: I am guessing your main thread is blocked with a lot of other actions. I have seen this many times wich causes effects like you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For posterity:**

The issues that, direct **frame-setting was occurring on a background thread.**

### To fix the issue, I needed to ensure that that code was getting run on the main thread.

*That being said,* since I could not post enough code to really substantiate this issue, I'm going to vote to close it as off-topic. Thanks for all your help!